# Center a ASP:Linkbutton inside a ASP:Gridview

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm using a ASP:Linkbutton with some CSS inside a ASP:Gridview and I was able to get it inserted but cannot get it centered in the column.  The code I'm running is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modify" ItemStyle-Width="1px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdModifyUser" runat="server" CssClass="ovalbutton">
        <span>
           Modify
        </span>
     </asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-Width="1px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDeleteUser" runat="server" CssClass="ovalbutton">
           <span>
              Delete
           </span>
        </asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

This code is encapsulated after my last /asp:BoundField and before /Columns inside my /asp:Gridview .
When this is run, it looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to get those buttons centered in the column.
I've tried as much HTML as I could find to try to center this but with no luck.

Also, you'll notice the code of **ItemStyle-Width:1px** in there too.  If I don't put that in, or something like it, I get this:
[image]

Thank you for your help & let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: `gridview` renders `table`. So apply `text-align:center` to proper columns.

Comment: No luck.  Created a separate CSS object called .center_object { text-align: center; } and then added it to the  cssclass of the asp:Linkbutton.  Nothing changed.